# Is $n^{3+\epsilon} + log(n^{3+\epsilon}) = O(n^{3+\epsilon})$?

Tags: big-o

Is `$n^{3+\epsilon} * log(n^{3+\epsilon}) = O(n^{3+\epsilon})$`?

(for `\epsilon > 0`)

I am not sure if multiplying `log(\epsilon)` doesn't affect to `O(n^{3+\epsilon})` term.

Comment: Did you test? What is the result?

Comment: I think this is the right page to post this https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

No. Assume that there is a constant *c* that exists, then you'd have:

```
n^(3 + ε) log(n^(3 + ε)) <= cn^(3 + ε)
          log(n^(3 + ε)) <= c
```

Clearly, that's not a viable constant as it is increasing for all sufficiently large *n*.